# Towing a 72 Chevy pickup

Tags: chevrolet, transmission, clutch, truck, towing

I was towing my truck to the bodyshop on a car dolly. Somehow it slipped into reverse and I kept going until I noticed smoke coming from the towed truck. When I stopped to look at what was happening there was coolant spilling everywhere and I could smell my burnt clutch. Which is where I think the smoke was coming from! Does anyone have any ideas as to the extent of the damage I may have caused and it did I destroy the engine as well as the transmission? Thanks for helping

Comment: Was the towed vehicle the one with the smoking clutch or the vehicle you were towing with? Does the engine turn over? If the clutch let go in the process, you've probably not done a lot of damage to the tranny/engine, but who really knows.

Comment: I'd agree with Paulster2. There is no way we could know the extent of damage done. It could be minimal. It could be very bad. The only way for you to know is to test things and get into it. Good luck.

Comment: The towed vehicle was smoking. I haven't had a chance to dive in yet. Work has me busy but very soon! I was just panicking and figured I'd give it shout out! Thanks for your replies! Will update when I open her all up!